# I want hover animation to be played only during non-selected nav links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's a link to my codepen: http://codepen.io/Chiz/pen/LpRQeY

Here's the embeded code:

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:link,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:visited,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(74, 74, 74, 1.00);
}
@-webkit-keyframes greenPulse {
  from {
    background-color: #749a02;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 9px #333;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #91bd09;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 18px #91bd09;
  }
  to {
    background-color: #749a02;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 9px #333;
  }
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 1.00);
  -webkit-animation-name: greenPulse;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
/* make width of all nav link boxes the same */

.nav li {
  float: left;
  width: 10em;
}
.nav li a:link {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
/* arrow pointer for selected nav bar tab by using CSS triangle trick */

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active {
  position: relative;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active:after {
  /* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work */
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(74, 74, 74, 1.00) transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 15px 30px 15px;
  content: "";
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -40px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MySiteLogo</a>
   </div>
            <div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Web</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Print</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Art / 3D</a></li> 
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Hover over the 4 links on the right. Everything works fine, except for 1 issue.
The link that is selected (the "Me" link") should NOT have the hover effect applied to it. The hover effect should be applied only onto non-selected nav links.

I think the problem is that "**@-webkit-keyframes**" section. It's being applied globally through the site. I tried putting it inside the "**.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover**" section but obviously, it's invalid syntax.

Tks!

Comment: Works fine on Codepen not on SO snippet I guess.

Comment: Nope, problem is on Codepen and on my browser preview as well.

Comment: @Xeon consider selecting an answer as best answer whichever you find best, if none solved your problem then feel free to elaborate your problem in detail..

Answer (score 1):

You've got several solutions here. Either use `!important` rule like this (on the very first css rule you've defined) -

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:link,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:visited,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus
{
    color:white !important;
    background-color:rgba(74,74,74,1.00) !important;
    box-shadow: none !important; /* see I've added box shadow also */
}
```

Another solution will be to cut and paste the above code in the last of your css. And in this case you won't need the `!important` rule.

See the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojzEJb).

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to override the animation of active link:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active > a:focus
{
    -webkit-animation-name:none

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line in CSS and then check it.

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active > a:focus{ -webkit-animation-name:none; background:none; color:#fff;}

Do let me know if you have any issue.

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active a,  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active,  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:link,  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:visited,  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus { color:white; background-color:rgba(74,74,74,1.00); }



 @-webkit-keyframes greenPulse {  from {
 background-color: #749a02;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 9px #333;
 }
  50% {
 background-color: #91bd09;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 18px #91bd09;
 }
 to { background-color: #749a02; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 9px #333; }
}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus { background-color:rgba(230,230,230,1.00); -webkit-animation-name: greenPulse; -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; }

/* make width of all nav link boxes the same */
.nav li { float:left; width:10em; }
.nav li a:link { display: block; width: 100%; text-align:center; }

/* arrow pointer for selected nav bar tab by using CSS triangle trick */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active { position:relative; }
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active:after { /* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work */
  border-color:transparent transparent rgba(74,74,74,1.00) transparent; border-style:solid; border-width:15px 15px 30px 15px; content: ""; margin: auto; position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: -40px; height: 0; width: 0; }

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active > a:focus{ -webkit-animation-name:none; background:none; color:#fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MySiteLogo</a> </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Web</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Print</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Art / 3D</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row"> </div>
</div>
```